# QueueClient get scheduled messages

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to get the scheduled messages from a queue but struggling to do this. I was able to with the deadletter but for some reason scheduled queue is a little different. Currently, via Queue Explorer I am unable to send messages in batches so was hoping to do this via my own console app.

```
        var client = new QueueClient(
            connectionString,
            $"{endpoint}/$Scheduled",
            ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
```

I was hoping to do this but I get the error

```
Invalid operation. Cannot access '$Scheduled' subqueue
```

Any ideas how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access scheduled messages sub-queue.
You'd need to peek messages and filter out based on their `Status`. If you're using track 2 SDK, there's an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10241) about getting the status.